# List.remove(x) in python

Tags: list, python-2.7

I am keep having this error when I tried to remove the second record a[1] or **((2, 4), 'b69 1qw', '2 Toronto Street', 'jack'**)  from the list. Knowing that d could be anywhere in the list. first/second...if the list was longer. I am an absolute beginner in python

```
a= [((78, 2), 'b69 13d', '2 Avenue Concorde', 'Emile'), ((2, 4), 'b69 1qw', '2    
   Toronto Street', 'jack')]
>>> d=(2,4)
>>> a.remove(d)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
 a.remove(d)
 ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 0):

The `remove(x)` function in the documentation.

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error
>   if there is no such item.

If you need to delete an item by index, then use `del`.

```
del a[1]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if you don't know in which position is d?

Comment: Then use `remove(d)`. But in your code `d = (2,4)`, and you don't have that element. You probably want `d = ((2, 4), 'b69 1qw', '2    
   Toronto Street', 'jack')`.